# Bootstrap column order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a page using Bootstrap. The layout is like this on a desktop:

```
image - text
text - image
image text
```

When it collapses into the narrower version, I (naturally) wind up with:

```
image
text
text
image
image
text
```

How can I make the narrow version look like this?

```
image
text
image
text
image
text
```

I'm using 3 rows, each with 2 col-md-6 columns. Can I change the order of the columns when it collapses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder your content with Bootstrap [Column Ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering). See docs.

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
.blue {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row red">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>This is the most demandable and most used image editing service all over the world for ecommerce product selling. Don’t worry, we make it easy to ensure all your images fit your ecommerce image editing guideline. We resize, crop, remove borders,
        and remove image background turning it to pure white, transparent or color background as per your guideline.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row blue">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
      <p>For web-shop owners, we introduce our additional delivery of web-ready images. Add the image specifications (like crop size 800×800 px ) and we will deliver web-ready image. We can fulfill the image size requirements for any ecommerce platform like
        Amazon, eBay, Shopify, bigcommerce, volusion, squarespace etc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row red">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>If you want to separate and modify different parts and features of the same product including its color, shape, and size, Multipath is the service you can take from us. We can deliver images with Alpha Channel, Layer Mask or Only Path.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row blue">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
      <p>You have many different color variations of the same product but do not want to spend time taking photos of each one of them? No worries! You don’t have to. We can change the color and size of the same product as per your instruction to save you
        from investing more of your time and money in taking photos.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap frame work is basically [Mobile First](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile) so for narrow version or in other words mobile, to achieve the following layout

```
image
text
image
text
image
text
```

Grid system must be mobile first, `col-xs-*`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Image</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Image</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Image</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Text</div>
</div>
```

Now on small or medium devices, you want following layout

```
image - text
text - image
image text
```

Can be achieved with `push and pull` [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Image</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">Image</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Image</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Text</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paxyz0sg/)